# Asp Controls not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am truing to use a Telerik List View. I just added a SqlDataSource and I want to give the select command at server side. But when i want to access it in .cs file SqlDataSource1 is not accessible even any control is not showing. I added a label when i tried Label1.Text than label1 is not accessible in .cs file.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PortalSite.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="category.aspx.cs" Inherits="NoidaPortal.category" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    .rdpWrap .RadInput, .rdpWrap .rdpPagerButton, .rdpWrap .rdpPagerLabel
    {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<div>
    <!-- content start -->
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function RequestStart(sender, eventArgs) {
                //disable ajax on update/insert operation to upload the image
                if ((eventArgs.get_eventTarget().indexOf("Update") > -1) || (eventArgs.get_eventTarget().indexOf("PerformInsert") > -1)) {
                    eventArgs.set_enableAjax(false);
                }
            }
        </script>

    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Panel ID="ListViewPanel1" runat="server">
                    <telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                        ItemPlaceholderID="CustomersContainer" DataKeyNames="ArchitectId" AllowPaging="True"
                        >
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <!-- Set the id of the wrapping container to match the CLIENT ID of the RadListView control to display the ajax loading panel
                     In case the listview is embedded in another server control, you will need to append the id of that server control -->
                            <fieldset id="FiledSet1" style="width:435px;">
                                <legend>Customers</legend>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="RadListView1"
                                                PageSize="5" Width="435px">
                                                <Fields>
                                                    <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="FirstPrev" />
                                                    <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric" PageButtonCount="6" />
                                                    <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="NextLast" />
                                                    <telerik:RadDataPagerPageSizeField PageSizeText="Page size: " />



                                                </Fields>
                                            </telerik:RadDataPager>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="CustomersContainer" runat="server" />
                                <div style="clear: both" />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <table style="width: 100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <%--<td style="width: 25%;">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnInitInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert Customer" OnClick="btnInitInsert_Click" />
                                        </td>--%>
                                        <td style="text-align:center; width: 75%;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSort1" runat="server" Text="Sort by:" Style="padding-right: 5px;" />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddListSort" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="-Select field to sort-" Value="" />
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Company name" Value="ArchitectName" />
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Sector" Value="Sector" />

                                                </Items>
                                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <!--The widths/heights of the fieldset/outer tables in the item/edit/insert templates should match to avoid wrapping or visual discrepancies
                         in the tiles layout-->
                            <fieldset style="float: left; width: 410px; height: 215px; margin-top:10PX;">
                                <legend style="font-weight:bold">
                                    <%# Eval("ArchitectName")%></legend>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%;" width="370px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-weight:bold; width:25%">
                                                                    Address:
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width:auto; width:75%;">
                                                                    <%#Eval("ArchitectAddress")%>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width:25%; font-weight:">
                                                                    City:
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <%# Eval("Contact1")%>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-weight:bold">
                                                                    Country:
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <%# Eval("Contact2")%>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-weight:bold">
                                                                    Phone:
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <%#Eval("Email_Id")%>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-weight:bold">
                                                                    Website:
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <%#Eval("Website")%>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                            </fieldset>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <fieldset style="width: 800px">
                                <legend>Customers</legend>No records for customers available.
                            </fieldset>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                     </telerik:RadListView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
   <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbPortalConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Architect]" >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

 /div>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
 </asp:Content>
```

and this is my aspx.cs class

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 namespace NoidaPortal
 {

      public partial class category : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
            {
                 if (IsPostBack == false)
                  {
                       string s = Request.QueryString["cat"];
                        string s1 = Request.QueryString["sub"];

                       **I Just want to give here a SqlDataSource.Select command**
                   }
            }
     }
```

Comment: Sounds like your codebehind file is messed up.  Post your ASPX page along with your codebehind file.

Comment: okk I m putting My code.

Comment: plz check it. I just put my code and code behi]

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible because you haven't mentioned which is the codebehind for your page. Add this as the first line to your aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="yourfile.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourProjectName.YourASPXPageName" %>
```

Comment: Just don't copy it, substitute your value.

Answer (score 0):

You have some stuff not allowed in your content placeholder because you're using a master.  The reason you're not getting intellisense on your controls is because the page won't complile.

Remove these tags:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<body> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Then try to compile your app.  Fix any errors thrown by the compiler and recompile.  Once the application is compilable, your intellisense should start working again.

Comment: Chris Gessler, Thanks for concerning now i removed these tags even than it is not working.. it compile well but when i want SqlDataSource in .cs file intellicence didn't show it.

Comment: and you're typing SqlDataSource2. ?

Comment: yes when i m typing sqlDataSource1 or sqlDataSource2 nothing is showing even if i use a label and trying to access label1. than also its not working..

Comment: c# is case sensetive.  sqlDataSource2 should be SqlDataSource2

Comment: yes i know i m using SqlDataSource1 or SqlDataSource2 than also it is not showing its property.by typing sql it must show SqlDataSource1 but it isn't showing..

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the solution here... I have to convert it to webApplication by right clicking on ProjectFolder and click on "Convert to Web Application". Than it's intellisense start working.